# Binding an image to the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I want to bind an image along with the mouse cursor using jQuery.

The following code works with firefox but not with IE8.

```
$('#cursor').css({
       left:  e.pageX,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
//"cursor" is the id of the <img>.
```

Do we have an alternate to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are not using jQuery to bind your event listener. For IE, the properties you would use for mouse coordinates are `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`

```
if(typeof e.pageX !== "undefined"){
    $('#cursor').css({
           left:  e.pageX,
           top:   e.pageY
    });
} else {
    $('#cursor').css({
           left:  e.clientX,
           top:   e.clientY
    });
}
```

Of course, if you were to use jQuery to bind your listeners, you wouldn't have to worry about this, since the event object passed to a handler bound with jQuery has the mouse coordinates normalised in the `pageX` and `pageY` properties cross browser:

```
$('document').mousemove(function (evt) {
    $('#cursor').css({
       left:  evt.pageX,
       top:   evt.pageY
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting its position to absolute and manipulating the top and left attributes. You can do it with jQuery like this:

```
$("#cursor").css({"position":"absolute","left":e.pageX+"px","top":e.pageY+"px"});
```

Or you can use plain old Javascript and do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("cursor").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("cursor").style.left = e.pageX+"px";
document.getElementById("cursor").style.top = e.pageY+"px";
```

But depending on which version of IE it is, you may need to use clientX and clientY rather than pageX and pageY.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#cursor').css({'top': e.clientY, 'left': e.clientX});
```